# vim multiple matches. 2mat, 3mat, matchadd() alternatives

Tags: unix, vim

I want to have highlights for multiple words. i normally do this in .vimrc-

```
:highlight HLONE ctermbg=grey ctermfg=white
:highlight HLTWO ctermbg=blue ctermfg=white
:highlight HLTHREE ctermbg=green ctermfg=white
nnoremap 1 :mat HLONE "<C-R><C-W>"<CR>
nnoremap 2 :2mat HLTWO "<C-R><C-W>"<CR>
nnoremap 3 :3mat HLTHREE "<C-R><C-W>"<CR>
```

But its not working for me at my current workplace for some reason. Presessing one highlights the way it should. but pressing 2 (2mat) gives error -

**E481: No range allowed**

its seems 2mat, 3mat, matchadd are not available. vim version is 6.3.

is there any workaround or alternative?

Comment: 6.3 is very old. Are you forced to use this version?

Comment: :(. yes. i login to a remote host via ssh. and cant do anything about what is and isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim 6.3 is from 2004; the `:2match` commands were only introduced in Vim 7.0. If you're stuck with that version, you can only use `:match`, or alternatively try `:syn keyword` (but that will interfere with the regular syntax highlighting).

Even without root / administrative rights, you can usually compile / install a local version of Vim.

Advertisement: If you find the multi-word highlighting indispensable and use it often, try out my [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666); it automates the process of `:2match`, offers many colors, and highlights in all windows (but requires Vim 7.2). On that page are also links to other such plugins, some of which still use syntax highlighting and may work even with Vim 6.